# How get tweets with two hashtags?

Tags: php, api, twitter

I'm using simple twitter API on php 7.1.

I'm trying to tweets which has both hashtags: #hashtag1 and #hashtag2.

On some question on this site I read about `AND` and `OR`. I'm trying `AND`, but it doesn't work.

Any idea? I read all twitter documentation, but find nothing.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what PHP library you are using, but this works against the API directly, using the `twurl` tool.

`twurl "/1.1/search/tweets.json?q=%23snow%20AND%20%23ice&tweet_mode=extended"`